# Java XML string literals abruptly terminated

Tags: java, xml, string

I have some Java code that looks like this:

```
String xml = "<string>" + escapeXml(input) + "</string>";

protected String escapeXml(String input) {
  return input.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
              .replaceAll("'", "&apos;")
              .replaceAll("\"", "&quot;")
              .replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
              .replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
}
```

`input` is a variable UTF-8 encoded string.

What I'm finding is that in some cases the `xml` string ends up being equal to `<string>` without the enclosing `</string>`.  Why might this be?  Is it possible for Java to evaluate `escapeXml` into something that truncates the string before `</string>` can be appended to it?

**UPDATE:** In response to Sotirios, let me add some clarifications.  The `xml` string is being saved to a SQLite database column, which in turn is parsed by another utility.  So far, I've noticed that this behavior occurs when the `xml` string saved to the database is either `<string>` or `<string>` with some non-ASCII Unicode character afterwards.

`input` is being fed automatically from a hook into an Android function.  Because everything is running on Android in a non-standard configuration, it's a bit difficult to debug to learn exactly what's going on.  I was hoping that there might be some obvious answer involving Java strings.

Comment: `that in some cases` Which cases specifically? A reproducible example is always ideal.

Comment: And why aren't you using an XML API anyway? That's usually a *much* better idea than trying to handle it yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't `s` be `input`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I had the same thought.  This is actually code from an OSS project called Introspy.  @Pshemo, yes, I changed some of the names for readability's sake but I forgot to change `s`.

Comment: Nothing can change the fact that you are appending `</string>` unless you use reflection to change the `String` literal (which I very much doubt). The behavior you are seeing must be coming from somewhere else and for some other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this, but I did fix my problem by modifying the `escapeXml` function to use a proper XML encoder (org.apache.commons.lang library).  I don't see how that would make a difference, but it did, and now the `xml` string is properly constructed.